# Linq query to filter contacts having same phone number

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a list of contacts where each contact (saved in Contact table) can have multiple numbers (saved in another table Contact_Phones)

```
public class Contact{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string First_Name {get; set;}
    public string Last_Name {get; set;}
    public List<Contact_Phones> Phones {get; set;}
}

public class Contact_Phones{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public int Type {get; set;}
    public string Phone_No {get; set;}
}
```

Now I want to filter contacts having same phone_no using Linq C# and merge those contacts.

Comment: How do you want to merge them? What is the final output you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var contactsWithduplicates = contacts
                     .Where(contact => contact.Phones.Any(phone => 
                             contacts.Any(contact2 => contac2 != contact && contact2.Phones.Contains(phone))))
                     .Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var query= ContactsRepo.GetAll()
           .SelectMany(contact => contact.Phones)
           .GroupBy(contactPhone => contactPhone.Phone_No)
           .ToList();
```

Comment: with Lazy Loading disabled it would give you just phones

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have you contacts in a list called `contacts`:

```
// Break into phones and contact id for example
var all_phones = from contact in contacts
            from phone in contact.Phones
            select new {contact_id = contact.ID, phone = phone.Phone_No};

// get only contacts that share the same phone 
var duplicates = from entries in all_phones
                 group entries by entries.phone 
                 into g where g.Count() >1
                 select g;
```